# Eliminate ng-change delay

Tags: angularjs

I have two select boxes. When "Canada" in one box is selected, I want to hide the "Canada" selection in the other box.

I have  already implemented it in my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ealonwang/41ahaspr/11/.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="originCountry" ng-change="hideCan()">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option ng-hide="hideOriginCan" value="CAN">Canada</option>
  </select>
  <select ng-model="destCountry" ng-change="hideCan()">
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option ng-hide="hideDestCan" value="CAN">Canada</option>
  </select>
</div>

angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.originCountry = "USA";
    $scope.destCountry = "USA";

    $scope.hideCan = function() {
      if ($scope.originCountry == "CAN") {
        $scope.hideDestCan = true;
      } else {
        $scope.hideDestCan = false;
      }
      if ($scope.destCountry == "CAN") {
        $scope.hideOriginCan = true;
      } else {
        $scope.hideOriginCan = false;
      }
    }
})
```

However, in my very big project (very very big), this implementation has a delay and won't work perfectly. Is there any way to eliminate this delay? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*very big project*"? I assume the amount of select boxes because the max amount of countries is somewhat limited.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the delay occurs?  Sheer size of the code?  Inefficient code?  Server latency?

Comment: This is a quite complicated project. Several guys are working on the front end part of this project and some are using jQuery. I will refactor all the code to AngularJs in next month. So now it is kind of hard to improve the performance and find the delay issue. Hope you guys understand.

Comment: But is this an example or 1:1 the code you are using? Are there more select boxes or countries in your actual code?

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Hi Marcel, this example won't even affect the big project at all. It is just two selection boxes which allow the user to select the origin and destination countries. I am just doing a UI minor change. I think there is an ng-change delay because we have too many $digest cycles running.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder I want to eliminate the delay here because this UI change works directly and instantly with the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want the *debounce* option for `ng-model-options`.  You can read more about it here -https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what causes your performance issues because I don't know anything about the surrounding code. Anyway here I just want to provide you an alternative using a filter:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.countries = ['USA', 'CANADA'];
  $scope.filterSelected = function(ignore) {
    return function(option) {
      return option !== ignore;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="originCountry" ng-options="country for country in countries | filter: filterSelected(destCountry)">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <select ng-model="destCountry" ng-options="country for country in countries | filter: filterSelected(originCountry)">
     <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Although I can't know how this implementation is acting performance wise when integrated in your project either.